# type signature of an enable_if'ed templated template constructor?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, constructor, enable-if

I usually declare my classes and templates, and then define their methods after (in the same header file, of course). I just find it easier to read that way. Well, I've come across a case where I can't figure out a working type signature to use in an out-of-class definition. Here's a simplified example of what I'm doing, that illustrates the problem:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
  {
    Foo(T a, T b);

    template 
      < class Iterator
      , enable_if< is_iterator<Iterator> >
      >
    Foo
      ( Iterator first
      , Iterator last
      );
  };

template <class T>
Foo<T>::Foo(T a, T b)
{ ... }

template <class T>
template
  < class U
  , WHAT_GOES_HERE?
  >
Foo<T>::Foo(U f, U l)
{ ... }
```

I have tried a number of things in the `WHAT_GOES_HERE` slot to try to get a matching signature, and I keep failing. I need the enable_if to distinguish the case where one passes in two objects of type T, and when one passes in a pair of Iterators. The code works fine if the templated constructor is defined inside the main template, which is how the code currently does it, but I'd much rather move the definition outside the declaration.

**EDIT:** I should mention that I can't just re-use enable_if<...> in the definition, because enable_if<...> assigns a default value for its type, which you cannot do in a definition that isn't also a declaration.

Comment: Do you really need SFINAE for this?  If you just declare the second constructor as `template <typename U> Foo(U first, U last);`, the first constructor will still be selected if the caller passes two objects of type `T`.

Comment: Type T is usually an arithmetic type, and I want to be able to pass in ints when T is unsigned and vice-versa, and not have the templated constructor get called (which was been happening before I used the enable_if)

Comment: Actually, you're not assigning a default value at all.  The second parameter for your template is an `enable_if< is_iterator< FirstParam > >`.  Sort of like if you expected an `int`.  It shouldn't compile and certainly would be impossible to use.

Comment: I was unclear. enable_if assigns a default type for its template parameter, which is the meta version of assigning a default value.

Comment: Template default parameters look like so: `template < typename T, typename T2 = xxxx >`

Comment: Exactly, and enable_if is a template, and has a template default parameter buried in its definition, which is why it can never be used in a type slot in a declaration.

Comment: @swestrup: Out of curiosity, how do you implement your `is_iterator` metafunction?

Comment: Its about 40 lines of code, so I won't paste it here, but I essentially check for a type either being some sort of pointer, or a class containing an embedded iterator_category member.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn't do it that way.  Here's the changes I would make:

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
  {
    Foo(T a, T b);

    template 
      < class Iterator
      >
    Foo
      ( Iterator first
      , Iterator last
      , typename enable_if<is_iterator<Iterator> >::type* = 0
      );
  };

template <class T>
Foo<T>::Foo(T a, T b)
{ ... }

template <class T>
template
  < class U
  >
Foo<T>::Foo(U f, U l, typename enable_if< is_iterator<U> >::type*)
{ ... }
```

This is straight out of the documentation for `enable_if`.

Comment: Interesting, I've read through the enable_if documentation several times, and it never occurred to me to treat a constructor as a nested function... If this works, then its definitely acceptible.

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/utility/enable_if.html section 3: "Constructors and destructors do not have a return type; an extra argument is the only option. "

Comment: Thanks! That did indeed do the trick. Does that mean that what I was trying before was impossible, in that there is no way to give a type signature that would have satisfied C++?

Comment: You should have been able to make a declaration simply by using the same parameter information.  You'd never have been able to use it though.  On the other hand, I didn't expect it to accept that kind of type as a parameter and compile.  I was pretty sure that was reserved to numeric types.

Comment: Using the same parameter information generates an error because the definition of enable_if has a default template parameter, but now that I think of it, that **shouldn't** be an issue, although it generates an error on my compiler (g++ 4.5)

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying to accomplish?  [I don't have an `is_iterator` type trait, so I've reworked your example using the C++0x type traits and utility libraries.  It should work the same way with the TR1 and Boost libraries.]

```
#include <utility>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct S
{
    // Constructor (1)
    S(T, T); 

    // Constructor (2)
    template <typename U>
    S(U, U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type* = 0);
};

template <typename T>
S<T>::S(T, T)
{ }

template <typename T>
template <typename U>
S<T>::S(U, U, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<U>::value>::type*)
{ }

int main()
{
    S<double> a(1.0, 2.0); // uses (1)
    S<double> b(1, 2);     // uses (2)
}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats more or less correct. I had to write my own is_iterator. I have no idea why its not standard in boost.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest you can do is:

```
template<class Iterator>
Foo
  ( Iterator first
  , typename enable_if<is_iterator<Iterator>, Iterator>::type last
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
template <class T>
struct Foo
  {
    Foo(T a, T b);

    template <class Iterator
      ,       class = typename std::enable_if
                       <is_iterator<Iterator>::value>
                       ::type
      >
    Foo
      ( Iterator first
      , Iterator last
      );
  };

template <class T>
Foo<T>::Foo(T a, T b)
{  }

template <class T>
template
  < class U
  , class >
Foo<T>::Foo(U f, U l)
{  }
```

Comment: I've tried this, and it doesn't work. I get a message saying that the definition doesn't match any declarations in my template. Although, I must say, this **should** work!

Comment: I tested it with g++-4.4 and clang.  However I had -std=c++0x for my tests and now that I double check, I think that is required.  Without it clang gives this warning: warning: default template arguments for a function template are a C++0x extension [-Wc++0x-extensions]
      ,       class = typename std::enable_if

Comment: Strange, your example DOES work, when I try it with my compiler. But when I try the same thing on real template, I get an error. I must be doing something wrong...

Comment: Forgetting "::value" or "::type" is an easy mistake to make.